# OpenGl Texture unit

Tags: opengl

’m observing a strange behavior from my application which I hope you can explain to me.
You see, I have these two 3D textures that are being sent to the fragment shader and are rendered perfectly OK. But there is a problem, As soon as I even create another texture (it’s a 1D texture), a black screen is being rendered instead of the correct former result.

About this 1D texture, I’m not even sending it to the fragment shader. The minute I call glTexImage1D(…) the black screen shows up. I comment this line and it goes away!!And the two textures are rendered.

I figured there has to be some kind of problem with texture units. Because when I run the application with gDebugger, the texture unit of one of 3D textures is THE SAME as the one assigned to the 1D texture.

I did not assign any texture unit to the 1D texture, I just created it. Apparently texture unit GL_TEXTURE0 is being automatically assigned to the 1D texture. The weird part is that although I use GL_TEXTURE2 and GL_TEXTURE3 for the 3D texture, one of them is being bound to GL_TEXTURE0 as a result of calling glTexImage1D!

Here is a snapshot from the textures list window of gDebugger:

Texture 1 (unit 2 ,bound3d)-enabled
Texture 2 (unit 0 ,bound1d)
Texture 3 (unit 0 ,bound3d)-Enabled (unit 3,bound3D)-enabled

Why is this happening?

the problem is not why texture 1D is being bound to GL_TEXTURE0, it is why it can affect the state of another already bound texture. the code is like this : 
.

```
...
// generating  the first texture_3d
glTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_3D,....);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D,id1);

    //render loop for the first texture_3d
    GLuint glEnum = GL_TEXTURE2;
    vtkgl::ActiveTexture(glEnum);
    glBindTexture(vtkgl::TEXTURE_3D,id1);
    program->setUniform("TEX1",2);

    // generating  the second texture_3d
    glTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_3D,....);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D,id2);

    //render loop for the first texture_3d
    GLuint glEnum = GL_TEXTURE3;
    vtkgl::ActiveTexture(glEnum);
    glBindTexture(vtkgl::TEXTURE_3D,id2);
    program->setUniform("TEX2",3);

    // generating  texture 1D
    glTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_1D,....);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D,id3);

    we expect GL_TEXTURE2 and GL_TEXTURE3 to be active but gDebugger indicates that GL_TEXTURE0 and GL_TEXTURE2 are active.
```

Comment: "Can you please explain to me why is this happening?" No. Because you didn't show us any code. You have a bug in your code. In all likelihood, you doing some "bind to edit" and not unbinding the object afterwards.

Comment: *"Apparently texture unit GL_TEXTURE0 is being automatically assigned"* - No, only if texture unit 0 is active, not if you didn't change it back to 0 after using 2 and 3 for the other texdures, since **OpenGL is a state machine**.

Comment: I have added source code  to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have both 1D and 3D textures bound to the same texture unit at the same time. To avoid this, either unbind the 3D texture: `glBindTexture()` or switch to a new texture unit: `vtkgl::ActiveTexture()` before binding the 1D texture.

As the above poster has stated, the call to `vtkgl::ActiveTexture()` must come before the corresponding call to `glBindTexture()`.

Comment: Thank you everybody for the replies.

Answer (score 4):

Call `glActiveTexture` BEFORE `glBindTexture`

glBindsTexture binds to CURRENT active texture, so in your current code you first you bind id1 to texture 0, then bind it again to texture2, then bind id2 to texture2 (replacing id1), etc.

Comment: Not sure about that. His code rather looks like a collection of code snippets from many different places. Some actual code from him would have been more helpful. But it's surely some error of this kind, +1.

Comment: @ChristianRau: "Not sure about that" Just read his code fragment, and you'll see it. If he provided invalid code fragment, that's not my problem.